# Appending conditional formatting like hex colors to a list using numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

In my original code the list that is modified isn't generated by a csv, but instead it comes from another function however for problems sake we'll generate the list from a csv file.

**I'm sure someone must known how to edit the python script lower down to fix the problem**

The problem/error/change in question is that I'm looking for a way to modify the python code so that any cells that are empty or contain `NA` are given a completely different hex color (not one that is in the gradient scale), however to explain the problem from the start.

**Data stored in csv format for visual and problem purposes.**

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,13,13.39%,42.7%,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,14,82%,41.9%,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,18,29.39%,41%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,22.3,44.4%,42.3%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4,44.2%,43.4%,Data
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4.1,49%,42.7%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.45,49.5%,42.42%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.29,20%,42.3%,Data
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.22,25%,41.2%,Data
```

**The data that needs to be modified is stored in list form as seen below**

```
[['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '13', '13.39%', '42.7%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '14', '82%', '41.9%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '18', '29.39%', '41%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '22.3', '44.4%', '42.3%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4', '44.2%', '43.4%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4.1', '49%', '42.7%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.45', '49.5%', '42.42%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.29', '20%', '42.3%', 'Data'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.2%', 'Data']]
```

**The expected output is as seen below:**

```
[['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '13', '13.39%', '42.70%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#F8696B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '14', '82%', '41.90%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '18', '29.39%', '41%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '22.3', '44.40%', '42.30%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4', '44.20%', '43.40%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#F8696B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData2', 'UniqueTest2', '4.1', '49%', '42.70%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#63BE7B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.45', '49.50%', '42.42%', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.29', '20%', '42.30%', 'Data', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B', '#FFEB84'], ['UniqueData3', 'UniqueTest1', '4.22', '25%', '41.20%', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#FFEB84', '#F8696B']]
```

**For visual purposes, if it was exported into a csv file it would look like:**

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,13,13.39%,42.70%,Data,#F8696B,#F8696B,#63BE7B
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,14,82%,41.90%,Data,#FFEB84,#63BE7B,#FFEB84
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,18,29.39%,41%,Data,#63BE7B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,22.3,44.40%,42.30%,Data,#63BE7B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4,44.20%,43.40%,Data,#F8696B,#F8696B,#63BE7B
UniqueData2,UniqueTest2,4.1,49%,42.70%,Data,#FFEB84,#63BE7B,#FFEB84
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.45,49.50%,42.42%,Data,#63BE7B,#63BE7B,#63BE7B
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.29,20%,42.30%,Data,#FFEB84,#F8696B,#FFEB84
UniqueData3,UniqueTest1,4.22,25%,41.20%,Data,#F8696B,#FFEB84,#F8696B
```

**As you can see they've all been given 3 hex colors, which in excel if you were to apply the colors to each cell would translate to:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQii1.png

**The code that M4tini created to "solve" the above problem is:**

```
import numpy as np

with open("testing.csv") as infile:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in infile]

def mapValues(values):
    values = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in values]
    colorMap = np.array(['#F8696B', '#F86E6C', '#F8736D', '#F8786E', '#F97E6F', '#F98370', '#F98871', '#FA8E72', '#FA9373', '#FA9874', '#FA9E75', '#FBA376', '#FBA877', '#FBAD78', '#FCB379', '#FCB87A', '#FCBD7B', '#FCC37C', '#FDC87D', '#FDCD7E', '#FDD37F', '#FED880', '#FEDD81', '#FEE382', '#FEE883', '#FCEB84', '#F6E984', '#F0E784', '#E9E583', '#E3E383', '#DCE182', '#D6E082', '#D0DE82', '#C9DC81', '#C3DA81', '#BDD881', '#B6D680', '#B0D580', '#AAD380', '#A3D17F', '#9DCF7F', '#96CD7E', '#90CB7E', '#8ACA7E', '#83C87D', '#7DC67D', '#77C47D', '#70C27C', '#6AC07C', '#63BE7B'])
    #colorMap = np.array(["low", "mid", "high"])
    values = np.asarray(values)
    _, bins = np.histogram(values, 49)
    mapped = np.digitize(values, bins)
    return list(colorMap[mapped - 1])

def mapAndAdd(finalList, tempList, v1,v2,v3):
    v1 = mapValues(v1)
    v2 = mapValues(v2)
    v3 = mapValues(v3)
    for i,j in enumerate(newList):
        finalList.append(j + [v1[i] , v2[i] , v3[i]])

uniqueDataSet = set()

finalList = []
for index, DataSet in enumerate(lines):
    if (DataSet[0] + DataSet[1]) in uniqueDataSet:
        v1.append(DataSet[2])
        v2.append(DataSet[3])
        v3.append(DataSet[4])

        newList.append(DataSet)
    else:
        if (index != 0):
            mapAndAdd(finalList, newList, v1,v2,v3)

        uniqueDataSet.add(DataSet[0] + DataSet[1])
        newList = [DataSet]
        v1 = [DataSet[2]]
        v2 = [DataSet[3]]
        v3 = [DataSet[4]]

mapAndAdd(finalList, newList, v1,v2,v3)

with open('testing_new.csv', 'wb') as new_csv:
    for line in finalList:
        new_csv.write(",".join(line) + "\r\n")

print finalList
```

**Now if we use the csv data:**

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,1,1,1,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,2,2,2,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,3,3,3,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,4,NA,4,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,5,5,5,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,,6,6,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,7,7,7,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,8,8,8,Data
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,9,9,9,Data
```

**We get the following error, which is because of the blank cell on Row 6, Column 2 and the same goes for Row 4, Column 3 where we have a cell containing `NA`**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testing.py", line 47, in <module>
    mapAndAdd(finalList, newList, v1,v2,v3)
  File "C:\testing.py", line 20, in mapAndAdd
    v1 = mapValues(v1)
  File "C:\testing.py", line 11, in mapValues
    values = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in values]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

**I'm looking for a way to modify the python code so that any cells that are empty or contain `NA` are given a completely different hex color not one that is in the gradient**

**For example the output should look like:**

```
[['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '1', '1', '1', 'Data', '#F8696B', '#F8696B', '#F8696B'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '2', '2', '2', 'Data', '#F98871', '#F98871', '#F98871'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '3', '3', '3', 'Data', '#FBA877', '#FBA877', '#FBA877'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '4', 'NA', '4', 'Data', '#FDC87D', '#808080', '#FDC87D'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '5', '5', '5', 'Data', '#FEE883', '#FEE883', '#FEE883'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '', '6', '6', 'Data', '#808080', '#DCE182', '#DCE182'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '7', '7', '7', 'Data', '#B6D680', '#B6D680', '#B6D680'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '8', '8', '8', 'Data', '#90CB7E', '#90CB7E', '#90CB7E'], ['UniqueData1', 'UniqueTest1', '9', '9', '9', 'Data', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B', '#63BE7B']]
```

**Which for visual purposes should look like:**

```
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,1,1,1,Data,#F8696B,#F8696B,#F8696B
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,2,2,2,Data,#F98871,#F98871,#F98871
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,3,3,3,Data,#FBA877,#FBA877,#FBA877
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,4,NA,4,Data,#FDC87D,#808080,#FDC87D
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,5,5,5,Data,#FEE883,#FEE883,#FEE883
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,,6,6,Data,#808080,#DCE182,#DCE182
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,7,7,7,Data,#B6D680,#B6D680,#B6D680
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,8,8,8,Data,#90CB7E,#90CB7E,#90CB7E
UniqueData1,UniqueTest1,9,9,9,Data,#63BE7B,#63BE7B,#63BE7B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, another attempt to "solve" it.

```
def mapValues(values):
    nValues = np.asarray(values, dtype="|S8")
    mask = nValues != 'NA'
    maskedValues = [float(i.split('%')[0]) for i in nValues[mask]]
    colorMap = np.array(['#F8696B', '#F86E6C', '#F8736D', '#F8786E', '#F97E6F', '#F98370', '#F98871', '#FA8E72', '#FA9373', '#FA9874', '#FA9E75', '#FBA376', '#FBA877', '#FBAD78', '#FCB379', '#FCB87A', '#FCBD7B', '#FCC37C', '#FDC87D', '#FDCD7E', '#FDD37F', '#FED880', '#FEDD81', '#FEE382', '#FEE883', '#FCEB84', '#F6E984', '#F0E784', '#E9E583', '#E3E383', '#DCE182', '#D6E082', '#D0DE82', '#C9DC81', '#C3DA81', '#BDD881', '#B6D680', '#B0D580', '#AAD380', '#A3D17F', '#9DCF7F', '#96CD7E', '#90CB7E', '#8ACA7E', '#83C87D', '#7DC67D', '#77C47D', '#70C27C', '#6AC07C', '#63BE7B'])
    _, bins = np.histogram(maskedValues, 49)
    mapped = np.digitize(maskedValues, bins)
    nValues[mask] = colorMap[mapped - 1]
    nValues[~mask] = "NA color"
    return nValues.tolist()
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting how you got around that problem. I tried several things including using numpy's `np.NaN` function but nothing worked. This works pretty much perfectly, I can adjust my other bit of code to make it work with blank data.